# While hitting the jsp page I am getting an error

Tags: java, jsp

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /Login.jsp. Reason:

    PWC6033: Unable to compile class for JSP

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Caused by:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Unable to compile class for JSP

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

I am using jdk1.8.0_131 and jetty 7.4.5.jar and jetty-runner 7.1.5.jar.
  I came to know that this is because of jdk and jetty version compatibility hence I increased jetty version to jetty 9.3.3 and jetty-runner 9.3.3 then I am getting the below error while starting the server:

```
10:47:58.029(06/19) WARN  RSF : Unexpected exception encountered
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/nio/SelectChannelConnector
    at com.lxnx.ols.rsf.http.server.HttpServer.<init>(HttpServer.java:38)
    at com.lxnx.ols.rsf.http.server.HttpServer.<clinit>(HttpServer.java:22)
    at com.lxnx.ols.rsf.http.server.AbstractRestServer.setAttribute(AbstractRestServer.java:455)
    at com.lxnx.ols.rsf.http.server.AbstractRestServer.start(AbstractRestServer.java:276)
    at com.lxnx.ols.rsf.http.server.AbstractRestServer.run(AbstractRestServer.java:232)
    at com.lexisnexis.vcmanager.VersionManagerServer.main(VersionManagerServer.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more
10:47:58.033(06/19) WARN  RSF : Shutting down server...
10:47:58.034(06/19) WARN  ChasmStateManager : Application has called internalShutdown().
10:47:58.556(06/19) INFO  RSF : Chasm state transition: STOPPING





Here i including the jsp code also that i am using.i didn't do any imports in this jsp file 
             <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
                        pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
                    <html>
                    <head>
                    <title>VCM Maintenance Portal</title>
                    <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                     function validateForm(){
                         //var userId = document.getElementById("userId");
                         if(document.myform.userId.value == null || document.myform.userId.value.length == 0){
                             alert("Please enter User ID");
                             return false;
                         }
                         if(document.myform.pwd.value == null || document.myform.pwd.value.length == 0){
                             alert("Please enter the password");
                             return false;
                         }
                     }
                    </script>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                    <FORM name="myform" ACTION="LoginServlet" onsubmit="return validateForm()" METHOD="POST">
                    <table width=100% height=100% cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">   
                        <tr height='30%'>
                            <td colspan="2" bgcolor=#cc0033>
                            <div id="header">
                            <h1>VCM Maintenance Portal</h1>
                            </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center">
                        <div>
                        <%
                            String message = (String) request.getAttribute("message");
                            if (message != null && message.length() != 0) {
                        %> <b><%=message%></b> 
                        <%
                        }
                        %>
                        </div>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr height='65%'>
                            <td width='60%'>
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                            <td width='40%' align='center'>
                                <table width='60%' height='40%'>
                                    <tr height='20%'><td colspan='2'><td></tr>              
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align='right'>User Id: </td>
                                        <td><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" id="userId" NAME="userId"></input></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align='right'>Password: </td>
                                        <td><INPUT TYPE="password" id="pwd" NAME="pwd"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td><INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" STYLE="color: #fff !important;
                                            background-color: #c03 !important;
                                            background-image: url('/images/GradButton.gif');
                                            background-repeat: repeat-x;
                                            border: 1px solid #c03;
                                            font: bold 70% Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                                            background-position: right 0;
                                            padding: 1px 4px 4px 4px;
                                            margin-right: 50x;
                                            text-decoration: none;
                                            cursor: pointer;
                                            margin: none;
                                            outline: none !important;
                                            overflow: visible;
                                            width: auto;"
                                            VALUE="Sign In" /></td>

                                    </tr>
                                    <tr height='20%'><td colspan='2'><td></tr>

                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>


                        <tr height='5%'>
                            <td colspan="2">
                            <div id="footer">
                            <div id="legal">Copyright© 2012 LexisNexis, a division of Reed
                            Elsevier Inc. All rights reserved.</div>
                            </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <input type="hidden" id="pageName" value="<%=request.getAttribute("pageName") %> "/>
                    </FORM>
                    </body>
                    </html>
```

Please help me in this I am struggling on this from past one week and it is running fine if am using jdk1.6

Comment: Your Login.jsp class is not compiling. Are you using a Java class that you forgot to import maybe ?

Comment: yeah, please show us the code of the JSP file that doesn't compile

Comment: i added my jsp also above please have a look